# Difference between pipelet and pipeline in SFCC

Tags: commerce-cloud, pipelines

What is the difference between pipelet and pipeline in SFCC?

After googling the question I did not find a clear answer on my question. So, I am sorry if it is an obvious one.

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly visit the below link. https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/27845T#Overview-PipeletsandPipelines-Pipelets https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/M25405#Concept-Pipelets-WhatarePipelets? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation topic: [Working with Pipelines](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SiteDevelopment/WorkingwithPipelines.html?cp=0_5_6)

A pipeline is a logical controller that is stored as XML and is displayed as a flow chart via an Eclipse plugin called [UX Studio](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SiteDevelopment/InstallUXStudio.html?cp=0_1_6_0). Pipelines have Start nodes and End nodes. Sometimes pipelines end with an Interaction node which indicates a template should be rendered to the client.

[image: Screenshot showing the editor interface for the Page.xml Pipeline from The SiteGenesis Reference Application; It includes two pipelines: Show and Include. Additionally, a side panel entitled "Palette" includes buttons for tools used to build pipelines.]

Pipelets are the components that are used to build a Pipeline. You can drag & drop Pipelets around in the interface and connect them with transitions. There are [system Pipelets](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/pipeletapi/html/api/pipeletList.html?cp=0_16_3_0) and you can define [custom pipelets as Javascript files](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/ScriptProgramming/PipelineScriptingQuickStartExample.html?cp=0_5_11_0) which have a function of this signature:

```
/**
 * Description of the scripting pipelet
 * @input InputParameterName : String Comment about this param
 * @output OutputParameterName : String Comment about this param
 */
function execute( pdict : dw.system.PipelineDictionary) : Number
{
  var success = false;
  // do your work and make sure to return PIPELET_NEXT or PIPELET_ERROR depending on the status of your work
  return success ? PIPELET_NEXT : PIPELET_ERROR;
}
```

Note that this is "the old way" and any new code should be written with Javascript controllers preferably in the style of [StoreFront Reference Architecture (SFRA)](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SFRA/GettingStartedwithSFRA.html).